# Array of dictionaries in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I would like to use something like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string>[] matrix = new Dictionary<int, string>[2];
```

But, when I do:

```
matrix[0].Add(0, "first str");
```

It throws " 'TargetInvocationException '...Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

What is the problem?  Am I using that array of dictionaries correctly?

Comment: Hmmm, you should get a `NullReferenceException`. Show more code.

Comment: Have you initialized `matrix[0]` to a new `Dictionary<int, string>`?  Also, `TargetInvocationException` is part of the `System.Reflection` namespace.  Where are you using reflection?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dictionary<int, string>[] matrix = new Dictionary<int, string>[] 
{
    new Dictionary<int, string>(),
    new Dictionary<int, string>()
};
```

You need to instantiate the dictionaries inside the array before you can use them.

Comment: You can also simlpify "new Dictionary<int, string>[]" to just "new []"

Comment: simple and elegant!

Answer (score 10):

Did you set the array objects to instances of Dictionary?

```
Dictionary<int, string>[] matrix = new Dictionary<int, string>[2];
matrix[0] = new Dictionary<int, string>();
matrix[1] = new Dictionary<int, string>();
matrix[0].Add(0, "first str");
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Dictionary<int, string>[] matrix = new Dictionary<int, string>[2];
```

Doing this allocates the array 'matrix', but the the dictionaries supposed to be contained in that array are never instantiated. You have to create a Dictionary object in all cells in the array by using the new keyword.

```
matrix[0] = new Dictionary<int, string>();
matrix[0].Add(0, "first str");
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to initialize the Dictionary.  Just put the line below **before** adding the item:

```
matrix[0] = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

Answer (score 3):

You've initialized the array, but not the dictionary.  You need to initialize matrix[0] (though that should cause a null reference exception).