# Initialize Array of Dictionary Randomly

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, dictionary

I am dealing with Array of Dictionaries and [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301225/array-of-dictionaries-in-c-sharp) is really helpful to achieve what I want so far.

But, now I want to initialize `Dictionary` for an array index based on the output of code.

I have a `Dictionary<int,string>`, where I am storing a `Id` as Key. I am having Array of 10 dictionaries as follows:

```
Dictionary<int, string>[] matrix = new Dictionary<int, string>[10];
```

So, based on the value of `(Id%10)`, i want to store that record in a respective array. For i.e., if `id= 12`, I want to store it in `matrix[2]`. If `id = 15`, i want to store it in `matrix[5]`.

Now,question is, how to check each time whether a dictionary is initialized for a particular index or not. If yes, than add the record to the dictionary else initialize the instance and then add the record to Dictionary.

Something like following:

```
if {} // if dict with id%10 is initialized then
{
    matrix[id%10].Add();
}
else
{
    matrix[id%10] = new Dictionary<int,string>();
    matrix[id%10].Add();
}
```

Edit: I know i can initialize all first using loop, but I want to initialize only when it's necessary.

Comment: @Adrian That'll check whether the Key is in dictionary or not. My question is different.

Comment: Right. Just check wether `matrix[index] == null`

Comment: If you have only 10 dictionaries in an array, wouldn't it be easier to instantiate them all just after creating the array?

Comment: @Adrian Thnx. Don't know how this hadn't come in my mind.

Comment: @dymanoid I have many array of dictionaries with arraysize more than 10. Hence i want to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Dictionary<int, string>[] matrix = new Dictionary<int, string>[10];
    int id = 0; // Number here
    int index = id % 10;

    if (matrix[index] == null)
    {
        matrix[index] = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    }

    int key = 0; // key you want to insert

    if (matrix[index].ContainsKey(key))
    {
        // Dictionary already has this key. handle this the way you want
    }
    else
    {
        matrix[index].Add(0, ""); // Key and value here
    }
```

Comment: ok. That's just too easy and really embarrassing for me. Thank you.

Comment: @HarshilDoshi No problem. Note that key check is also needed here. Without that you might end up getting exceptions

Comment: @mjwills why? We just want to see if a key exists or not.

Comment: The advantage of `TryGetValue` is that if `// Dictionary already has this key. handle this the way you want` needs to access the object stored in the `Dictionary` it can do so without another hash lookup.

Comment: Ah in that case. Sure. Only if we need the existing value associated with the key though.